# Adjusting S-Curves (Sigmoid Functions) with Hyperparameters

Tags: logistic-curve

I can define the sigmoid function in R with:

```
library(tidyverse)

s_curve <- function(x) {
    y <- 1/(1 +  exp(1)^-x)
    return(y)
}

df <- tibble(x = seq(-3, 3, 0.1)) %>% 
    mutate(y = s_curve(x))
```

And plot it with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Hight I adjust the function to include hyperparameters that can control the bounds/limits and the "stretch" of the curve"?

For instance, how can I define a sigmoid-like function that is bounded by ylim(5000, 20000) and stretches at x = c(10, 15) or x = c(12, 15)?

Like:

[image]

Comment: try `?plogis`, and `curve(plogis,-5,5)`

Answer (score 2):

Consumed the better part of my day.

```
s_curve <- function(x, ymin, ymax, x50L, x50U) {

    a = (x50L + x50U) / 2
    b = 2 / abs(x50L - x50U)
    c = ymin
    d = ymax - c

    y = c + ( d / ( 1 + exp( b * (x - a) ) ) )

    return(y)
}
```

Where `ymin` is the floor, `ymax` is the ceiling, `x50L` & `x50U` are the lower and upper bounds for containing 50% of the values.

Example:

```
df <- tibble(x = seq(0, 30, 0.5)) %>% 
    mutate(y = s_curve(x, ymin = 5000, ymax = 20000, x50L = 11, x50U = 14))
```

Graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line() + xlim(0, 30) + ylim(0, 35000)
```

[image]

Comment: "Consumed the better part of my day" -- (+1) c'est la vie. Also the wiki details this pretty nicely: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function